# Unknown error logs

Tags: arch-linux, logging

I am getting a lot of these error messages logged into my tty consoles making them unusable. I have no clue what causes these errors. I have a small doubt that its related to my HDD.

```
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7683.593354] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7683.593357] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199243] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199277] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199282] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199292] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:80:11:f2/00:00:19:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199294]          res 41/40:08:87:11:f2/00:00:19:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199300] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.199303] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Jun 12 23:48:57 localhost kernel: [ 7686.304240] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 435294599
```

Answer (score 5):

This clearly shows there are read errors on a hard drive, due to media errors.

See what e.g.

```
# smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

turns up.

Comment: I'd start with backing up anything mildly important and finding a replacement drive; then tinkering with `smartctl`

Comment: as provided, smartctl will only read SMART values from a drive. Granting you can do extensive damage (or rather, just get the drive to do a lot of work, which might force a marginal drive over the edge), reading its already recorded values wont do this.

Comment: Warnings of imminent failure should trigger your "what's my backup and recovery plan" reflex, not "I wonder what the details of the failure are".

Answer (score 4):

`I have a small doubt that its related to my HDD.`
I have ***no doubt*** that it is related to your hard disk.
The error messages say so in about as many ways as they can (naming `ata1.00` & `dev sda`).

Your drive is throwing media errors. This almost certainly means it is dying (which you can confirm using the SMART information Jeff's answer mentioned).

Make backups. Replace the disk. Restore from the backups.
I'm not sure what else you expect us to tell you...

Answer (score 2):

You want to tune /proc/sys/kernel/printk if you need the messages off your console.

And yes, these messages means your hard drive or hard drive cabling are severely bust.